# (x / y) * 100 in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

So I can't get this to work for some reason, I'm trying to calculate `(x / y) * 100` where `x` is a variable determined by user input and `y` is an output variable. It's pure Javascript. I think I'm probably just being dumb but I can't figure it out.

Currently I'm putting

```
parseInt(input2Value) / parseInt(output2Value) * 100;
```

```js
function calculate(){
    var input1Value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var input2Value = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    
    var output1 = parseInt(input1Value) * 4.5;
    document.getElementById('output1').value = output1;
    
    var output2 = parseInt(output1) + parseInt(input2Value);
    document.getElementById('output2').value = output2;    
}
```

```html
Input1 : <input type="text" id="input1" value="25000" />
Input2 : <input type="text" id="input2" value="30000" />
<button onClick="calculate();">Calculate</button>

Output1 : <input type="text" id="output1" />
Output2 : <input type="text" id="output2" />
```

Comment: Provide reproducable example

Comment: I'm trying to add the answer of the formula as third output to this http://jsfiddle.net/6vqd4vnq/

Comment: @LouisDown: Okay...not seeing that code in the snippet (which rnevius helpfully copied from the fiddle for you -- code in questions must be **in** the question). Can't help you find the bug in code you haven't shown.

Comment: The parseInt(input2Value) / parseInt(output2Value) * 100; doesn't work for you? Because the code you provide with your edit works just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, you've mis-named the second variable:

```
parseInt(input2Value) / parseInt(output2) * 100
```

`output2Value` doesn't exist...so there's no math do be done.

And a runnable snippet:

```js
function calculate(){
    var input1Value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var input2Value = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    
    var output1 = parseInt(input1Value) * 4.5;
    document.getElementById('output1').value = output1;
    
    var output2 = parseInt(output1) + parseInt(input2Value);
    document.getElementById('output2').value = output2;    

    var output3 = parseInt(input2Value) / parseInt(output2) * 100;
    document.getElementById('output3').value = output3;
}
```

```html
Input1 : <input type="text" id="input1" value="25000" /><br>
Input2 : <input type="text" id="input2" value="30000" /><br>
<button onClick="calculate();">Calculate</button><br><br>

Output1 : <input type="text" id="output1" /><br>
Output2 : <input type="text" id="output2" /><br>
Output3 : <input type="text" id="output3" />
```